# Conversion from dual fisheye coordinates to equirectangular coordinates

Tags: c++, fisheye, spherical-coordinate

The following [link](http://paulbourke.net/dome/dualfish2sphere/) suggests that we can convert dual fisheye coordinates to equirectangular coordinates using the following equations:

```
// 2D fisheye to 3D vector
phi = r * aperture / 2
theta = atan2(y, x)

// 3D vector to longitude/latitude
longitude = atan2(Py, Px)
latitude = atan2(Pz, (Px^2 + Py^2)^(0.5))

// 3D vector to 2D equirectangular
x = longitude / PI
y = 2 * latitude / PI
```

I applied to above equations to write my source code like this:

```
const float FOV = 220.0f * PI / 180.0f;
float r = sqrt(u*u + v*v);
float theta = atan2(v, u);
float phi = r * FOV * 0.5f;
float px = u;
float py = r * sin(phi);
float pz = v;
float longitude = atan2(py, px); // theta
float latitude = atan2(pz, sqrt(px*px + py*py)); // phi
x = longitude / PI;
y = 2.0f * latitude / PI;
```

Unfortunately my math is not good enough to understand this and not sure if I write the above code correctly, where I tried to guess the values for px, py and pz.

Assume my camera FOV is 220 degrees, and the camera resolution is 2880x1440, I would expect the point (358, 224) for rear camera in the overlapped area and the point (2563, 197) for front camera in the overlapped area would both map to a coordinate close to (2205, 1009). However the actual mapping points are (515.966370,1834.647949) and (1644.442017,1853.060669) respectively, which are both very far away from (2205,1009). Please kindly suggest how to fix the above code. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are building the equirectangular image, so I would suggest you to use the inverse mapping.

Start with pixel locations in the target image you are painting. Convert the 2D location to longitude/latitude. Then convert that to a 3D point on the surface of the unit sphere. Then convert from the 3D point to a location in the 2D fisheye source image. In Paul Bourke page, you would start with the bottom equation, then the rightmost one, then the topmost one.

Use landmark points like 90° long 0° lat, to verify the results make sense at each step.

The final result should be a location in the source fisheye image in the [-1..+1] range. Remap to pixel or to UV as needed. Since the source is split in two eye images you will also need a mapping from target (equirect) longitudes to the correct source sub-image.